# @media screen and background-color problem. Supposed background-color is not being displayed

Tags: html, css, responsive

I tried everything in the stack overflow.
I use microsoft edge and I updated it.
I tried adding `!important`
I tried putting @media{} after all the background-color declarations.

But the supposed background color is not being displayed after I resize and make the screen smaller or the make the browser window smaller!

It should display tomato color when resized, but instead it displays white background-color.

```
#hakkimda {
            padding-top: 30px;
            /*clear: both; float left ve 
    float right varsa buna etkiyen 
    onları iptal etmek için*/
            height: 330px;
            background-color: tomato;
            color: black;
        }
@media screen and (max-width:992px) and (min-width: 0px){
            .medyalarim1 {
                width: 100%;
            }

            #hakkimda img{
                margin-top:30px;
            }
            #hakkimda{
                background-color: tomato !important;
            }
        }
```

```
<div id="hakkimda">
        <img src="../../eyeTers.jpg" alt="">
        <p>Coherent Games
            Böbreküstü bezlerinizi patlatır. Size adrenalin kusturur.
        </p>
    </div>
```

Here is the larger part of the code:

```
#hakkimda {
            padding-top: 30px;
            /*clear: both; float left ve 
    float right varsa buna etkiyen 
    onları iptal etmek için*/
            height: 330px;
            background-color: tomato;
            color: black;
        }

        #hakkimda img {
            border: 5px dashed grey;
        }

        #hakkimda p {
            white-space: pre-line;
            text-transform: capitalize;
        }

        /* #hakkimda p span{
    font-size: larger;
    font-weight: bold;
} */
        #hakkimda p::first-line {
            font-weight: bold;
            text-decoration: underline;
            font-size: 30px;
            letter-spacing: 3px;
        }
        @media screen and (max-width:992px) and (min-width: 0px){
            .medyalarim1 {
                width: 100%;
            }
            
            #hakkimda img{
                margin-top:30px;
            }
            #hakkimda{
                background-color: tomato !important;
            }
        }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="coherentgames">
        <span class="coherentgamesyazi">
            Coherent Games Korku Oyunları Tasarlar
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="medyalarim">
        <div class="medyalarim1">Konusu apartman dairesinde geçer.
            <p>Kapalı ortamda en iyi korku oyunu</p>
        </div>
        <div class="medyalarim1">Konusu ötanazi'dir.
            <p>Kasaba ortamında geçen oyundur.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="medyalarim1">Konusu antolojik korkudur.
            <p>Hikayeler her türlü ortamda geçmektedir.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="hakkimda">
        <img src="../../eyeTers.jpg" alt="">
        <p>Coherent Games
            Böbreküstü bezlerinizi patlatır. Size adrenalin kusturur.
        </p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Where is the problem?

as @A Haworth requested here s the complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
        }

        div {
            width: 100%;
            height: 300px;
            text-align: center;
            color: orangered;

        }

        #coherentgames {
            /*bu 3 yazı tipi benzer yazı tipleri 3. tip tüm ,
        browserlarda var ilki yoksa diğeri o yoksa en sondaki kullanılır*/
            background: url(../../COHERENTGAMESLOGO.png);
            background-size: 100% 300px;
        }

        .coherentgamesyazi {
            font-size: 20px;
            text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px white;
            background-color: lightgreen;
        }

        .medyalarim {
            /*En yukarda aynı seviyedeki tüm div'lerin 
    width değeri 100% verilmiş zaten*/
            /*medyalarim div'inin içersindeki elemanları 
    float left yap yani sola yasla*/
            /*float:left;*/
            /*içersindeki tüm yazılarım fontunu kalınlaştırır*/
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .medyalarim1 {
            padding-top: 10px;
            width: 33.33%;
            height: 300px;
            /*bu div'e float left dememize rağmen div içersindeki yazılar 
    float left yapmıyor sola yaslanmıyor merkezde duruyor*/
            float: left;
        }

        .medyalarim1 {
            padding-top: 10px;
            width: 33.33%;
            height: 300px;
            float: left;
        }

        .medyalarim1 {
            padding-top: 10px;
            width: 33.33%;
            height: 300px;
            float: left;
        }

        .medyalarim1:nth-child(1) {
            /*medyalarım class'ının 1. child'ı anlamına gelir*/
            background: url("../../fetuspt.jpg") no-repeat;
            background-image: 100% 100%;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        .medyalarim1:nth-child(1) p {
            color: turquoise;
        }

        .medyalarim1:nth-child(2) {
            /*medyalarım class'ının 1. child'ı anlamına gelir*/
            background: url("../../mary.jpg") no-repeat;
            background-image: 100% 100%;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        .medyalarim1:nth-child(2) p {
            color: green;
        }

        .medyalarim1:nth-child(3) {
            /*medyalarım class'ının 1. child'ı anlamına gelir*/
            background: url("../../sounthbound.jpg") no-repeat;
            background-image: 100% 100%;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        .medyalarim1:nth-child(3) p {
            color: purple;
        }

        #hakkimda {
            padding-top: 30px;
            /*clear: both; float left ve 
    float right varsa buna etkiyen 
    onları iptal etmek için*/
            height: 330px;
            background-color: red;
            color: black;
        }

        #hakkimda img {
            border: 5px dashed grey;
        }

        #hakkimda p {
            white-space: pre-line;
            text-transform: capitalize;
        }

        /* #hakkimda p span{
    font-size: larger;
    font-weight: bold;
} */
        #hakkimda p::first-line {
            font-weight: bold;
            text-decoration: underline;
            font-size: 30px;
            letter-spacing: 3px;
        }
        @media screen and (max-width:992px) and (min-width: 0px){
            .medyalarim1 {
                width: 100%;
            }
            
            #hakkimda img{
                margin-top:30px;
            }
            #hakkimda{
                background-color: tomato !important;
            }
        }
        
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="coherentgames">
        <span class="coherentgamesyazi">
            Coherent Games Korku Oyunları Tasarlar
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="medyalarim">
        <div class="medyalarim1">Konusu apartman dairesinde geçer.
            <p>Kapalı ortamda en iyi korku oyunu</p>
        </div>
        <div class="medyalarim1">Konusu ötanazi'dir.
            <p>Kasaba ortamında geçen oyundur.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="medyalarim1">Konusu antolojik korkudur.
            <p>Hikayeler her türlü ortamda geçmektedir.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="hakkimda">
        <img src="../../eyeTers.jpg" alt="">
        <p>Coherent Games
            Böbreküstü bezlerinizi patlatır. Size adrenalin kusturur.
        </p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Screenshots:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smBHC.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUU7h.jpg)

I tried the same code for firefox browser too but it did not work there either, here is the screenshot: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXnFk.png)

Comment: You have `tomato` background twice for both resolutions. Try to change the first one to yellow and see that it works.

Comment: @Azu if I make the first declaration blue it becomes blue when it is wider than 992px but, again, when it is lesser than 992px it is white again does not display the supposed tomatoe color as responsive background-color

Comment: Running the code you have given and putting blue for the first background color, the color changes to tomato perfectly OK when I resize the viewport down. I am wondering therefore is there is some interaction with your img - could you put them into your snippet so we can see them too?

Comment: @AHaworth I put the whole code as you've requested.

Comment: @AHaworth I put the screenshots too

Comment: Sorry, I can't see the images.

Comment: @AHaworth I solved the problem: Putting height: 100% into #hakkimda{ height: 100%; background-color: tomato !important; } solves the problem!!!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem:
Putting

```
height: 100%;
```

into,

```
#hakkimda{ 
background-color: tomato !important; 
}
```

Solution:

```
#hakkimda{ 
height: 100%;
background-color: tomato !important; 
}
```

This solves the problem!!!

Answer (score 0):

When you resize your window than before the 992 screen resolution, it will take tomato color as the background color.

```css
#hakkimda {
            padding-top: 30px;
            /*clear: both; float left ve 
    float right varsa buna etkiyen 
    onları iptal etmek için*/
            height: 330px;
            background-color: red;
            color: black;
        }

        #hakkimda img {
            border: 5px dashed grey;
        }

        #hakkimda p {
            white-space: pre-line;
            text-transform: capitalize;
        }

        /* #hakkimda p span{
    font-size: larger;
    font-weight: bold;
} */
        #hakkimda p::first-line {
            font-weight: bold;
            text-decoration: underline;
            font-size: 30px;
            letter-spacing: 3px;
        }
        @media screen and (max-width:992px) and (min-width: 0px){
            .medyalarim1 {
                width: 100%;
            }
            
            #hakkimda img{
                margin-top:30px;
            }
            #hakkimda{
                background-color: tomato !important;
            }
        }
```

```html
<div id="coherentgames">
        <span class="coherentgamesyazi">
            Coherent Games Korku Oyunları Tasarlar
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="medyalarim">
        <div class="medyalarim1">Konusu apartman dairesinde geçer.
            <p>Kapalı ortamda en iyi korku oyunu</p>
        </div>
        <div class="medyalarim1">Konusu ötanazi'dir.
            <p>Kasaba ortamında geçen oyundur.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="medyalarim1">Konusu antolojik korkudur.
            <p>Hikayeler her türlü ortamda geçmektedir.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="hakkimda">
        <img src="../../eyeTers.jpg" alt="">
        <p>Coherent Games
            Böbreküstü bezlerinizi patlatır. Size adrenalin kusturur.
        </p>
    </div>
```

[image: Normal Screen]

[image: Responsive Screen - Tomato color is overwriting red color]

Comment: why not tomato, but red??

Comment: That was just an example you can choose any color you want. If you want tomato color as responsive color then you can add ( background-color: tomato; ) in media query and in first declaration you can add any color you want.

Comment: hey, it does not display the red color either

Comment: I've already did that but it does not work. That's the problem.

Comment: Can you please visit this codepen and try to resize window. - https://codepen.io/abhishekshahj/pen/bGrodzQ

Comment: in codepan it works but not in my browser microsoft edge

Comment: I think you are not using updated browser as in my edge browser it is working perfectly.

Comment: I updated my edge browser right now but the problem persists. I shared my whole code by the way.

Comment: You can check my screenshots for the Microsoft Edge browser.

Comment: Here are my screenshots. I saw yours.

Comment: Code that you have provided here works perfectly. So now I have to check the actual code that you have written. Can you please provide me that code or can you update your work on any site so that I can check that and try to resolve your problem.

Comment: I put the whole code into my main post. I do not know how to update my work on any site. Is it okay for you?

Comment: Can you see my screenshots at least?

Comment: You can check my codepen I have inserted all your code there and it works fine for me. I think you should clear your cache or try to hard reload your browser and yes I can see your screenshots.

Comment: Okay I will try what you said.

Comment: I tried the code for the firefox too but it did not work there either I put the screenshot into my main post

Comment: Hey hey I solved it.

Comment: putting height: 100% into 
#hakkimda{
                height: 100%;
                background-color: tomato !important;
            } solves the problem!!!

Comment: Can you please guess why this worked? I dont know why it worked.